# Multiplayer Gaming via python

Tags: python, terminal, multiplayer, game-development

I wrote a pretty simple terminal based poker game (ascii art ftw), and right now it's multiplayer, but you basically have to pass a single computer around.
Is there a simple(ish) way to make it so two people could connect from separate machines and access the same game to play together at the same time? It doens't have to be fancy, and doesn't need to be graphical, as long as we have terminal access.

I'm not sure about how to do this or if it's practical, but just want to learn and explore some options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but I can give you some vague answers.

First, you need to design a simple protocol. A very simple line-based protocol should work fine: UTF-8 text, newlines separating messages, spaces separating parameters. For example, you could have these client->server messages:

```
JOIN name
SAY message with spaces
FOLD
RAISE amount
# ...
```

… and these server->client messages:

```
OK
ERROR error message
JOINED player name with spaces
LEFT player
SAID player message with spaces
NEWHAND player player player player…
DEALT player face suit
ANTED player amount
CHECKED player
# ...
```

The nice thing about a protocol like this is that you can type it manually with `telnet` or `nc`, so you don't even need a client for testing.

Now you need to build a server that implements that protocol, and build the game logic into the server.

A threaded server may be the simplest thing here. Then main thread kicks off a game thread, which spends most of its time blocking on a `Condition` waiting for players to act. It also blocks on `accept`, kicking off a new client thread for each connection, which spends most of its time blocking on `for line in self.sock.makefile():`. Add a `Lock` inside the client object to allow other threads to safely send messages. Then you just need a collection of client objects with a lock around it, and you're done.

Since I've got a chat server sitting around with a similar design, let me adapt some bits out of it to give you a skeleton.

First, here's the entire main thread:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
clients = []
game = Game()

ssock = socket.socket()
ssock.bind(('', 12345))
ssock.listen(5)
while True:
    sock, addr = ssock.accept()
    with lock:
        clients.append(Client(addr, sock, len(clients))
```

The `Client` object is a standard dispatcher:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, addr, sock, number):
        self.sock = sock
        self.name = '<{}> (not logged in)'.format(addr)
        self.number = number
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serve)
        self.thread.start()

    def send(self, msg):
        with self.lock:
            self.sock.send(msg)

    def run(self):
        for line in self.sock.makefile():
            args = line.rstrip().split()
            cmd = args.pop().upper()
            method = getattr(self, 'do_{}'.format(cmd), None)
            if method is none:
                self.write('ERROR unknown command {}\n'.format(cmd))
            else:
                try:
                    method(*args)
                except Exception as e:
                    self.send('ERROR in {}: {}\n'.format(cmd, e))
                else:
                    self.send('OK\n')
```

You probably also want a `broadcast` function:

```
def broadcast(msg):
    with lock:
        for client in clients:
            client.send(msg)
```

Then you write methods on `Client` for each command. Basically, each `elif response == 'FOO'` you had in your menu code becomes a `do_FOO` method, and each `print` becomes a `broadcast`, and… that's about it. I'll show a more complicated one later, but here's what most of them will look like:

```
def do_SAY(self, *msg):
    broadcast('SAID {} {}'.format(self.number, ' '.join(msg)))
```

Finally, there's the `Game` object. This runs on its own thread, just like each `Client`. For the most part, its `run` method is the same logic as in your sequential, non-networked game. Of course you have to call `broadcast` instead of `print`, but that's easy. The only tricky bit is that you need a bit of synchronization.

For example, before starting a new hand, you have to copy the list of players (and maybe some other related game state) so other threads can modify it without affecting the current game, and you also need to wait until there are enough players so you don't go starting hands with 1 person playing himself. So:

```
def new_hand(self):
    with self.condition:
        while len(self.players) < 2:
            self.condition.wait()
        players = self.players
    # all your existing sequential logic
```

And you need to add a `join` method for the clients to call from their own threads:

```
def join(self, player):
    with self.condition:
        self.players.append(self)
        self.condition.notify()
```

So, in the `Client` object:

```
def do_JOIN(self, name):
    self.name = name
    game.join(self)
    broadcast('JOINED {} {}'.format(self.number, self.name)
```

Let's make waiting for bets as complicated as possible, just to see how easy it is even in the worst case. If you want to bet out of turn, you can. Everyone can see your bet, and if circumstances change, you're committed (e.g., if you call, then the guy ahead of you raises, you're calling his new bet). So, here's what we do:

```
def wait_for_bets(self, bettor):
    with self.condition:
        while self.bets[self.bettor] is None:
            self.condition.wait()
        bettor, bet = self.bettor, self.bets[self.bettor]
        self.bets[self.bettor] = None
    # handle the bet
```

And here's how a `Client` submits a bet:

```
def bet(self, player, bet):
    with self.condition:
        self.bets[player] = bet
        self.condition.notify()
```

For example, in `Client`:

```
def do_FOLD(self):
    game.bet(self, 'fold')
```

Obviously there's a bunch of code to write. But the point is that there's nothing complicated beyond what's already shown above, or already in your existing game.

Comment: Wow, nice work on this answer. Pity you've only got a single upvote for it!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to host a server of some kind, and write a program than handles requests containing certain kinds of data, and communicates it back to the client.  Since this isn't a real time game, you don't need to mess around too much with TC/IP, UDP, or anything, simple HTTP requests will probably be fine.

In fact, you can even use a free service called [Scoreoid](http://www.scoreoid.com).  I'm using it for my games.  It's designed for high score leaderboards, but it'll probably suit your needs.  It's super easy to use.  Since the API works entirely out of URLs, you can just use the standard library's `urllib` modules.  This is probably a very good way to get started with this sort of thing.